# Why am I getting this error when trying to print a matrix in c?

Tags: c, matrix

I've searched several videos and tutorials on how to print a matrix and they led me to this:

```
void
init(void)
{
    board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
                   {5,  4,  3},
                   {2,  1,  0}};
}

void
draw(void)
{                  
    for (int row = 0; row < d; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < d; column++)
        {
            printf("%i", board[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code makes sense. I understood it. And i've seen people using it on videos to print a matrix and it works! But when I try, I get the error:

> "expected expression before ‘{’ token" On the line: "board[3][3] = ... "

And I have no idea why. Do any of you know what's wrong?

Comment: There could be a syntax error in the previous line.

Comment: This looks good. Probably the previous line is having some syntax error!

Comment: Probably you are not in C99 compiler mode. Loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode.

Comment: You're probably missing a semicolon on the previous line.

Comment: @40two But the error message isn't for the `for` line.

Comment: Which compiler?  This code won't work in Visual Studio for the reason given by @40two.

Comment: There error is *before* the opening `{` - that includes all the code that precedes the line.  The compiler reports the error on the line at which the code stopped making sense *in context*, and you have not provided the context in which this fragment, which is itself valid; it is the preceding code that renders it invalid.

Comment: The data type of array is missing

Answer (score 4):

This isn't valid C:

```
board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
               {5,  4,  3},
               {2,  1,  0}};
```

Either initialize it when you declare it, or assign each element one at a time.

Comment: Or use C99 compound literals in conjunction with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 4):

```
board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
               {5,  4,  3},
               {2,  1,  0}};
```

Must be:

```
int board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
                   {5,  4,  3},
                   {2,  1,  0}};
```

But as pointed out by @dreamlax, this only works if `board` is declared and initialized as global.

This code works on C99 using compound literals:

```
void
init(void)
{
    memcpy(board, (int[][3]){{8, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 0}}, sizeof board);
}
```

The portable way is:

```
void
init()
{
    int temp[][3] = {{8, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 0}};

    memcpy(board, temp, sizeof board);
}
```

Comment: Except in this case, `board` will no longer exist after `init` ends. `board` will have to be at file scope to be accessible in `draw` (or passed in as a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Possible errors in your program:-

1) There is a missing semicolon in the line preceding `{` or in the main function where `init(void)` is called.

2) Change

```
board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
               {5,  4,  3},
               {2,  1,  0}};
```

to

```
int board[3][3] = {{8,  7,  6}, 
               {5,  4,  3},
               {2,  1,  0}};
```

3)

```
for (int row = 0; row < d; row++)

for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
```

declaring variables within the loop itself is allowed only in latest `C99` compiler mode. So make it,

```
int row, column;
for (row = 0; row < d; row++) {
for (column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
} }
```

4) You have not declared `d` (array size) anywhere. Either make it a macro using `#define` on the top of the file or pass it as an argument in the function `draw(void)` or define it explicitly inside the function `draw`.

But anyway I don't see the sense of using an array of constant size `3` in the `init` function and then using a variable to access its elements in `draw` function.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to say that d and board are already declared as global variables. And I'm using c99 compiler mode. I'll try to specify everything next time. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the keyword `int` that is also the datatype of the array variable:

```
void 
init(void)
{
    int board[3][3] = {{8, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 0}}; 
}
```

Comment: Please excuse my inundations , I answered using my phone.

Comment: When you do this,board will only be accessable in the init function,and not in any other function

Answer (score -1):

Try This Code:-

```
int board[3][3] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} 

for (int row = 0; row <3; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        printf("%d ", board[row][column]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the valid code is

```
int board[3][3] = {8,  7,  6, 5,  4,  3, 2,  1,  0};

for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        printf("%d ", board[row][column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `%i` is equivalent to `%d`.

Comment: Hard-coding for-loop bounds like this makes it more difficult to change the size of the array.